# Swift" Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT in PresentViewController

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

I wonder why my code not working which where I follow in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tt2xfrRk3Ck). It always keep throwing this error:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

I'm new to Swift and iOS development.

Error throws in:

```
self.presentViewController(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Code:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
          if let user = user {
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeView") 
            self.presentViewController(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
          } else {
            self.loginButton.center = self.view!.center
            self.loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
            self.loginButton.delegate = self
            self.view!.addSubview(self.loginButton)

            self.loginButton.hidden = false
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly go to your main.storyboard and check that your story board segues are named correctly one should be named "HomeView".

Then try cleaning your product (SHIFT + CMD + A or 'Product --> Clean').

Hope this works.

Comment: Not working but I found this error message 

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "HomeView" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'`. What does it mean?

Comment: I drag a UITableViewController and use that instead of the UIViewController and the error gone but I wonder why I can't use UIViewController? and also when I create a new file in cocoa touch no UIViewController option. Now, I'm having a question what's the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I thought the UIViewController is missing in the Cocoa touch option. So, I fixed by changing the subclass to UIViewController instead of UITableViewController.